# How does the Docker network feature provide service discovery?

Tags: docker

As the docker docs say:

> Before the Docker network feature, you could use the Docker link feature to allow containers to discover each other and securely transfer information about one container to another container
>
> While links are still supported in this limited capacity, you should avoid them in preference of Docker networks. The link feature is expected to be deprecated and removed in a future release.

However, I think the Docker link feature provides us with automatic service discovery, which I can find nowhere explaining the network feature can do as well. Am I missing something?

If I create my own bridge network, and connect my web container and db container to it, how can my web container discover the db container automatically?

When I say service discovery, I means a certain container can discover other containers' service IP address and port in a bridge network with something like `<name>_PORT_<port>_<protocol>`  which works in the link feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will still have the same functionality with the new network feature. All containers on the same network will know about each other as if you linked them with the old `--link` feature. So instead of linking each of your containers you simply put them in small networks as required and you are done.

This approach also gets rid of the old and rather annoying link breakage that accured if you had to update a linked container.

Comment: Well, the truth is that docker helps us grab the service info like ip and port and set them in /etc/hosts, which is almost the same as the legacy link feature. So what Erik say is correct, and this question could be closed. Thanks Erik